# URL-based access management using Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, azure-active-directory

I have simple ASP.NET MVC survey generator, that based on the URL displays various forms and persists data input from user:

- http://survey.mydomain.com/ConferenceFeedback
- http://survey.mydomain.com/DailyReport
- etc.

Some of these *subapps* should be accessible by everyone, some by specific set of users. My user store is Azure AD. Is there is any Azure AD related feature that is a good match for my authorization scenario, where I could assign user rights on Azure side and just validate some claims or roles in my app per user request?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into application roles. You can define roles representing the various subapps you want to model, and you can assign users to them accordingly. On the application side, you can examine the incoming claims set and decide whether the user has the necessary role claims for accessing the portion of the app they are requesting. See https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims for a sample app demonstrating the approach.